# Binding Row to Validation Rule WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I want to bind `TextBox`'s `Tag` (which is inside a `DataGrid`), to validation rule's CurrentLegStrategy property (which is a `DependencyProperty`). Although I've done something similar with Deal dependency property using a global tunnel object, however not able to figure out, what would be the tunnel for CurrentLegStrategy (ideally should be coming from the bound data to `DataRow` or to the bound data to `TextBox`'s tag)?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PremiumProp">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockLeft}" Tag="{Binding Strategy}" x:Name="txtPremiumProp">                     
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <Binding Path="AbsolutePremium" StringFormat="{}{0:#,##0.00####}" Converter="{StaticResource _DoubleConvertor}">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <Control:MBSStrategyBasedDoubleValidation ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationTag="premabs"
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid positive (+) premium (also check the reference which is required for auto calculation)!">
                        <Control:MBSStrategyBasedDoubleValidation.Deal>
                            <Control:DealObject Deal="{Binding Tag, Source={StaticResource TradeTunnel}}" CurrentLegStrategy="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=txtPremiumProp}"/>
                        </Control:MBSStrategyBasedDoubleValidation.Deal>
                    </Control:MBSStrategyBasedDoubleValidation>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then I also tried,

```
<TextBlock.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <FrameworkElement x:Name="strategySource" Tag="{Binding Tag, Source={x:Reference txtPremiumProp}}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>    
</TextBlock.Resources>
```

With the following:

```
CurrentLegStrategy="{Binding Path=Tag, Source={StaticResource strategySource}}"
```

Cannot find resource named 'strategySource'. Resource names are case sensitive.

Comment: As it is, this is like blind guessing game with that's going on. I'd suggest you try using `RelativeSource` binding instead of `ElementName` in your `DealObject`. If that doesn't work, create a **simple** project that demonstrates your problem and give the code here (and possibly link your sample project) that we can use to troubleshoot your issue.